# my sql substring reverse placement values

Tags: mysql, substring

I need some help with mysql subtring and trim.  I have a data in a column which looks like

```
uvw.xyz.com!johndoe@abc.efg.com
```

I am trying to get everything before `@` and flip flop username and first domain and remote ! and preceeding domain after `@`, so the result would be `johndoe@uvw.xyz.com`.

I got something like..

```
select substr(m1.username, 10, 50) 
from (select username from my_table where username like '%!%')) as results;
```

But this is looking at the fixed fields and I need to go off from `@` caracter along with ! and then flip floop.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SET @var = 'uvw.xyz.com!johndoe@abc.efg.com';
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var, '@', 1), '!', -1) AS local,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var, '@', 1), '!', 1) AS domain
```

**Result**

```
|   LOCAL |      DOMAIN |
-------------------------
| johndoe | uvw.xyz.com |
```

To get a concatenated value, you can use:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var, '@', 1), '!', -1), '@',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var, '@', 1), '!', 1)) AS email
```

**Result**

```
|               EMAIL |
-----------------------
| johndoe@uvw.xyz.com |
```

You would replace `@var` with `m1.username`

Comment: Thanks NJK,  appreciate yur help, I tried but I am getting null values, my sql looks likes this...

Comment: select concat(substring_index(substring_index(@m1, '@', 1), '!', -1),
'@',
substring_index(Substring_index(@m1, '@', 1), '!', 1))
from (select username from mytable
where username like '%!%')as m1;

Comment: Why are you using `@m1` ? You should replace `@var` with `m1.username` per your original code.

Comment: Really apprecaite your help.